# Get only TimeZone field from new Date() in java

Tags: java, date, timezone

**Requirement :** I want to get only TimeZone field from new Date(), As of now  from **new Date()** ,I am getting result as

**Wed Jul 23 19:37:20 GMT+05:30 2014**,But I want only **GMT+05:30**,Is there any way to get only this?

PS:I dont want to use **split** for getting timezone field.because this is my final option for achieving above requirement.

Comment: A `Date` does not have a timezone.  When you print its string form, you see the timezone returned by [TimeZone.getDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Calendar` class and likely, the implementation `GregorianCalendar`. A lot of the `Date` functions have been deprecated in favor of using `Calendar`. Java 8 has the `Clock` API, but I'll assume Java 7 here.

That way you can do this:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
TimeZone tz = calendar.getTimeZone();
```

And work from there.

Answer (score 0):

import **java.util package** and use **GregorianCalendar** method.

```
int second, minute, hour;
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

second = date.get(Calendar.SECOND);
minute = date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
hour = date.get(Calendar.HOUR);

System.out.println("Current time is  "+hour+" : "+minute+" : "+second);
```

**Don't use Date and Time class of java.util package as their methods are deprecated means they may not be supported in future versions of JDK.**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to work with a `String` input you can do something like this:

```
// format : dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
String date = "Wed Jul 23 19:37:20 GMT+05:30 2014";
Pattern pattern = Pattern
    .compile("^\\w{3}\\s\\w{3}\\s\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s?(.*)\\s\\d{4}$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(date);
if (matcher.matches()) {
  String timezone = matcher.group(1);
  // beware : according to the Date.toString() documentation the timezone
  // value can be empty
  System.out.println(timezone);
} else {
  System.out.println("doesn't match!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Generate String With Offset But No Date and No Time

Your question is inaccurate. A java.util.Date has no time zone (assumes to always be in UTC). The JVM's time zone is applied in the object' `toString` method and in other formatting code that generates a String representation. Therein lies your solution: use a date-time formatter that generates a String containing only the offset from UTC without the date or the time-of-day portions.

## Avoid `java.util.Date` & `.Calendar`

Avoid using the bundled java.util.Date and .Calendar classes as they are notoriously troublesome. Instead use either Joda-Time or the new java.time package. Both support time zones as part of a date-time object.

## Joda-Time

Here is how to generate a String representation of a DateTime in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "ZZ" );
String offset = formatter.print( dateTime );  // generates: +05:30
```

In Joda-Time 2.3 you can ask a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object for its assigned time zone as an object. You may then interrogate the [DateTimeZone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
DateTimeZone timeZone = dateTime.getZone();
String id = timeZone.getID();
```

Comment: While I am a fan of `Joda-Time` and use it in my projects, you can still work around it if you're really worried about your library footprint.

Comment: Date and Calendar are not as bad as Joda evangelists seem to want to believe.  They certainly are not notoriously troublesome.  And as Davio rightly points out, the trade-offs of enlarging one's application with an additional library and dependency on a third party library need to be considered.

Comment: @VGR You'll have to include both Sun and Oracle on that list of Joda Evangelists, as they chose to supplant those old .Date/.Calendar classes with the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) added to Java 8 and inspired by Joda-Time. If Sun & Oracle could give up on those classes, perhaps you should consider doing so as well.

Comment: I always use java.time (except when legacy APIs require otherwise).  But you didn't espouse the use of java.time, you recommended using a third-party library.  More important is that Date and Calendar do work very well, and the notion that they are "notoriously troublesome" is not what I would choose to put in a factual answer.